# CORS not working in specific app - Django

Tags: django, cors, backend

I have an existing app called auth, which lets new user create an account or get an auth token after logging. Here everything seems alright. No CORS problems are present, but when I started a new app called Blog and tried to access its views via an Axios request, I get CORS error: no access allow origin headers are present even when my CORS policy is initialized.

Here is snippet of my `settings.py`:

```
Django settings for backend project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.2.9.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-3mr!aqng!tc!*ko7i!*&y9x8k-*y$@1pc+$g!_^-aol4!vd@tn'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'django_rest_passwordreset',

    'corsheaders',

    'auth_app',
    'blog'
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'backend.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'backend.wsgi.application'
# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PARSER_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser',
    ],
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication'
    ],
}

AUTH_PWD_MODULE="django.contrib.auth.password_validation."

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": f"{AUTH_PWD_MODULE}UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": f"{AUTH_PWD_MODULE}MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": f"{AUTH_PWD_MODULE}CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": f"{AUTH_PWD_MODULE}NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

MEDIA_ROOT =  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads')
MEDIA_URL = '/uploads/'

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

#CORS
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
```

As you can see, the CORS is initialized as it should be, even my auth app is working properly with it. So why is this happening when I try to access endpoints of Blog app?

Comment: Move `corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware` to the top of your middleware. The CORS middleware needs to be executed before any auth middleware, because preflight requests do not carry credentials.

Comment: That was the cause, thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on @jub0bs comment - I agree that the issue you are experiencing may be caused by the CORS middleware component being at the bottom of your list of installed middleware. Try moving this middleware component to the top of your middleware list, and see if that solves the problem.

As mentioned on the [django-cors-headers GitHub page](https://github.com/adamchainz/django-cors-headers):

*CorsMiddleware should be placed as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django's CommonMiddleware or Whitenoise's WhiteNoiseMiddleware. If it is not before, it will not be able to add the CORS headers to these responses.*